# Why are props getting from Redux not defined

Tags: reactjs, redux, mern

I use the starter template from [mern.io](http://mern.io).
When I try to run the following code I get the error: "ReferenceError: props is not defined"

EventDetailPage.js :

```
import React, {PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

// Import Actions
import {fetchEvent} from '../../EventActions';

// Import Selectors
import {getEvent} from '../../EventReducer';

function EventDetailPage(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{props.event.name}</h3>
    </div>
  // null
  );
}

// Actions required to provide data for this component to render in server side.
EventDetailPage.need = [params => {
    return fetchEvent(params.id);
  }
];

// Retrieve data from store as props
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    event: getEvent(state, props.params.id)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EventDetailPage);
```

fetchEvent (The API call is working) :

```
export function fetchEvent(id) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return callApi(`events/${id}`).then(res => dispatch(addEvent(res.event)));
  };
}
```

getEvent :

```
export const getEvent = (state, id) => state.events.data.filter(event => event.id === id)[0];
```

routes.js :

```
<Route
  path="/events/:name-:id"
  getComponent={(nextState, cb) => {
    require.ensure([], require => {
      cb(null, require('./modules/Event/pages/EventDetailPage/EventDetailPage').default);
    });
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how debugging works:

There are two places where you use the variable `props`:

```
      <h3>{props.event.name}</h3>
```

, which suggests that you should test to call `EventDetailPage(...)` independently (unit test) to check that this function works well, and

```
function mapStateToProps(state, props) {
  return {
    event: getEvent(state, props.params.id)
```

, which if it does not work would mean that Redux API is broken - it isn't -, but to make sure you can try to `console.log(props)` before returning.

From the code I can read, I think it fails somewhere that is not copied in your snippets, but since you don't provide the complete traceback (at least file and line number), it is quite difficult to know.